# Log Template Generator

Tags: python, regex, pattern-recognition

From the logs, I would like to find Unique logs or rather unique log template.
And use a custome String like < XXX > to show the blanks.

Example,

```
Server Stats 1001 created by 12, hosted.
Hosting Failed by 12
Server Stats 1003 created by 14, hosted.
Hosting Failed by 14
```

We could have 2 Unique template.

```
Server Stats <XXX> created by <XXX>, hosted
Hosting Failed by <XXX>
```

We could ignore the Logs which does not match at Repeat.

Comment: There is at least one library to do this. But I don't remember the name, you"ll have to Google yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Is this regex ok?

```
Server Stats (\d+) created by (\d+), hosted.
Hosting Failed by (\d+)
```

Python code:

```python
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = (r"Server Stats (\d+) created by (\d+), hosted.\n"
    r"Hosting Failed by (\d+)")

test_str = ("Server Stats 1001 created by 12, hosted.\n"
    "Hosting Failed by 12\n"
    "Server Stats 1003 created by 14, hosted.\n"
    "Hosting Failed by 14")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

[This is a demo on regex101.](https://regex101.com/r/0olnx0/1)

Comment: The logs may be numerous,  and the intention is to collate similar logs and generate templates.